# Redirect in nodejs not opening playstore

Tags: node.js, android-intent

Hi when I fire a url from mobile its opening the playstore URL in browser itself its not opening in playstore

my node code goes like this.

```
//controller.js
exports.app = function (rq, rs){
    rs.redirect('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fiverating.android');
}

//app.js
app.get('/app', controller.app);
```

so when I fire url `fiverating.com/app` form browser it opens in the same browser, should I add some other values in response before redirecting

Comment: why you don't want to return the `url` from backend to client side and then redirect to that URL?

Comment: @Talgat Medetbekov I am new to node, I didnt understand what you suggested . could you please explain

Answer (score 1):

For example in server side just return an url where you want redirect to:

```
//controller.js
module.exports.app = function (rq, rs){
  rs.json({
    url: 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fiverating.android'
  });
}
```

and in client side redirect to that url (example in angularjs):

```
$http.get('/api/app')
  .success(function (response) {
    window.location.href = response.url;
  });
```

Comment: I am new to node, how to run javascript in client side, should I add a file in javascripts folded in path and add the above mentioned code

Comment: Just provide me a code where you sending request to backend? I'll show you how redirect.

Comment: thanks for reply Talgat, I mentioned my code in the question itself.